# Scraping from PythonAnywhere

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pythonanywhere

I have a free account on PythonAnywhere from where I am trying to run the following script that locally works just fine.

I am wondering if the error I get is for technical reasons or just that PythonAnywhere forbids people to scrap from their platform for certain websites only?

Do you know of other free websites where I would be allowed to scrap anything?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def scrapMarketwatch(address):
    #creating formatting data from scrapdata
    r = requests.get(address)
    c = r.content
    sup = bs(c,"html.parser")
    print(sup)


scrapMarketwatch('http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/future/sp%20500%20futures')

print('\n\n\n PARAGRAPH \n SPACE \n\n\n')

scrapMarketwatch('https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/USDJPY:CUR')
```

I get the following error:

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py",
>   line 376, in increment
>       raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.bloomberg.com', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /quote/USDJPY:CUR (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot
>   conn ect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403
>   Forbidden',))) During handling of the above exception, another
>   exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/sylvester83/scrapit/try2.py", line 20, in 
>       scrapMarketwatch('https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/USDJPY:CUR')   File "/home/sylvester83/scrapit/try2.py", line 10, in scrapMarketwatch
>       r = requests.get(address)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in
>   get
>       return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in
>   request
>       return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
>   488, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
>   609, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line
>   485, in send
>       raise ProxyError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.bloomberg.com', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /quote/USDJPY:CUR (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot
>   connect to proxy.', OSEr ror('Tunnel connection failed: 403
>   Forbidden',)))

Comment: Bloomberg does not appear on their whitelist so it is a coding problems?

Answer (score 5):

PythonAnywhere free accounts are only allowed to access external sites that are on their [whitelist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/). Those permitted sites offer a machine API. You can ask for other sites to be added but not if you are going to scrape them.

Comment: Besides that, you can't run a script more than 100 seconds which isn't really helpful.